# Is there anyway to define the artifacts paths dynamically in Gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i have a template that i don't want to be modified as follows:

```
build: 
      script: 
        - ...
      artifacts:
        name: $BINFILE
        paths: [$ARTIFACTS_PATH]
```

and gitlab-ci.yaml that includes that template and the following vars

```
BINFILE: demo-bin-files
ARTIFACTS_PATH: "Build"
```

the artifacts NAME is substituted correctly by the var BINFILE but the var ARTIFACTS_PATH is not and throws an error while i start the job

```
Uploading artifacts...
 WARNING: --artifact-format: no matching files      
 ERROR: No files to upload
```

What i want here is that user pass only the paths that he want to upload as artifacts.
Can i do this or Gitlab doesn't support that ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't

but you can achieve this using shell script.

Set the `artifacts:` path to a temp folder and in the last step of your `script:` or `after_script:` section, copy all the content that you generate dynamically to the temp folder

it will solve your problem until Gitlab add this feature

Comment: Can you please give me the example of it

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and there's a simple fix - use the template as ana actual template.

*template.yml* (note the dot in the job name denoting it as a template)

```
.build: 
  script: 
    - ...
```

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
build:
  extends: .build
  artifacts:
    name: demo-bin-files
    paths:
      - Build
```

You can even define common artifact settings in the template like so:

*template.yml*

```
.build: 
  script: 
    - ...
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 6 hours
```

and *.gitlab-ci.yml* remains the same.